# How might I give a variable custom metadata?

Tags: python, python-3.x, metadata

Other than declaring the variable as a new object, is there a way I could apply extra information to a python variable that I could later refer back to?

```
someVar = ... # any variable type
someVar.timeCreated = "dd/mm/yy"
# or
someVar.highestValue = someValue
# then later
if someVar.timeCreated == x:
    ...
# or 
if someVar == someVar.highestValue:
    ...
```

I see that this is essentially just an object, but is there a neat way I could do this without declaring an object separate to the python variable object itself?

Comment: You can't assign attributes to an object unless that's supported, which most built-in types don't support. So no, you need to make something custom if you want something like that.

Comment: Also important: variables and objects are completely separate categories of things in Python. See https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: I'd just inherit from `object`. For example, `class custom_obj(object): pass` allows you to make `custom_obj`s that you can give custom properties.

Comment: @JakobLovern You don't need to inherit from `object`. This is Python 3.x. (And even in 2.x, you could add arbitrary attributes to old-style classes, so, while inheriting from `object` was a good idea, it still wouldn't be relevant to this question.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instances of user-defined classes (classes defined in Python source code) allow you to add whatever attributes you want (unless they have `__slots__`). Most built-in types such as `str`, `int`, `list`, `dict`, don't. But you can subclass them and then be able to add attributes, and everything else will behave normally.

```
class AttributeInt(int):
    pass

x = AttributeInt(3)

x.thing = 'hello'

print(x)  # 3
print(x.thing)  # hello
print(x + 2)  # 5 (this is no longer an AttributeInt)
```

Comment: I wonder why they made custom objects for subclassing, such as [UserDict](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/collections.html#collections.UserDict) then. How safe might it be to just subclass something like int or dict, I wouldn't know.

Comment: Not unexpectedly, it looks like wrapping int slows down operations on e.g. integers, considerably. For example if trying something like `timeit.timeit('a*b', 'class Int(int): pass;\na,b=Int(1000),Int(4000)'), number=10000000`. But if it's a collection object it may become in some scenarios negligible.

Comment: @matanster The `UserDict`, `UserList`, and `UserString` classes came from a time when it was not possible to inherit directly from `dict`, `list`, and `str`, as indicated by the documentation comment "The need for this class has been partially supplanted by the ability to subclass directly from" each of these types. So, it is perfectly safe to subclass those, as well as `int` and `float`, etc.